# Re-saisir, resaisir ou ressaisir pour « saisir de nouveau » ?

Tags: orthographe, préfixes

Je me demandais quelle était l'orthographe correcte de ce mot dans le contexte de saisir (un texte à la machine, par exemple) de nouveau.

*Re-saisir* est peut-être correct, mais ne me semble pas très élégant ?

*Resaisir* paraît correct et élégant, mais n'est pas reconnu partout, d'abord par mon correcteur orthographique. L'irrégularité de prononciation est commune pour les mots à préfixes (*homosexuel*, *asymétrique*, *resucée*, etc). [C'est reconnu](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/resaisir) par le Wiktionnaire.

Ressaisir paraît être un mot tout autre, mais peut-être usé souvent à tort… par exemple pour la forme « se ressaisir » qui me paraît éloignée dans son sens.

Existe-t-il une règle pour départager ces formes ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Le Robert l'orthographie *ressaisir* avec un premier sens de « saisir à nouveau », que vous écrivez *re-saisir*. C'est aussi la forme retenue pour le verbe pronominal *se ressaisir* qui signifie « rentrer en possession de », « reprendre possession de ».

Le *TLF* n'indique que l'orthographe [*ressaisir*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/resaisir).

On trouve dans le Wiktionnaire les entrées *ressaisir* et *resaisir*. La deuxième orthographe n'est pas académique, bien quelle soit complétement intelligible.

Il est donc préférable de redoubler le premier *s* dans vos écrits.

Dans un contexte moins soutenu, pour insister sur l'obligation de saisir à nouveau on pourra écrire *re-saisir*, accompagné d'une typographie d'attention.